# Datagrid in DataTemplate loses its selection when navigating to another screen and back, even if databound SelectedItem is maintained

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection

I have a WPF application following MVVM where my `ViewModel` has a `SelectedObject` property. In the `DataTemplate` for the `ViewModel`, there is a `DataGrid` with `SelectedItem` bound to `ViewModel.SelectedElement`.

Also in the same screen I have a form which display a lot of properties (with databinding) of `SelectedObject`.

Problem is: my MainWindow has a ContentControl where I put ViewModels that have DataTemplates, so I can switch ViewModels and the presentation follows. When I select an item in DataGrid, go to another screen (by switching ViewModels without shuting them), and switch back, the DataGrid selection (visually speaking) is lost, even though the databound `SelectedObject` property is still what it should be (tested with breakpoint), and I manually raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the ViewModel.

So, the question is: How can I recover the visually selected state of a DataGrid when a DataTemplate is re-rendered from its ViewModel?

EDIT: some code from my project:

ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Paciente> ListaPacientes {
        get { return _lista_pacientes; }
        set {
            _lista_pacientes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ListaPacientes);
        }
    }
    ObservableCollection<Paciente> _lista_pacientes;


    public Paciente PacienteSelecionado {
        get { return _paciente_selecionado; }
        set { _paciente_selecionado = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged(() => PacienteSelecionado);
        }
    }
    Paciente _paciente_selecionado;
```

View:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="TelaPacientes" DataType="{x:Type vm:TelaPacientesViewModel}">

                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single"
                    CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="Linen"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaPacientes}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding PacienteSelecionado, Mode=TwoWay}">

                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Strings.TelaPacientes_CPFLista}" Binding="{Binding CPF}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="80"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static res:Strings.TelaPacientes_NomeLista}" Binding="{Binding Nome}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Post us code please. Are you sure the selection gets "lost" or is the selection just set to inactive which will be displayed with a slightly grey brush.

Comment: It's a lot a code to post, but I'll see what I can do. As for the visual aspect of the selection, it is completely lost, not grayed out, not dashed rectangle (focus), every row has the same unselected appearance.